# python url decode %E3

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, urllib, urldecode

I get some wikipedia URL from freebase dump:

url 1: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_Miguel_de_Castro_Brand%25C3%25A3o_Costa

url 2: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_Miguel_de_Castro_Brand%E3o_Costa

They both refer to the same page on wikipedia:

url 3: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_Miguel_de_Castro_Brandão_Costa

`urllib.unquote` works on url 1

```
url = 'Pedro_Miguel_de_Castro_Brand%25C3%25A3o_Costa'
url = urllib.unquote(url)
url = urllib.unquote(url)
print url
```

result is

```
Pedro_Miguel_de_Castro_Brandão_Costa
```

but not work on url 2.

```
url = 'Pedro_Miguel_de_Castro_Brand%E3o_Costa'
url = urllib.unquote(url)
print url
```

result is

```
Pedro_Miguel_de_Castro_Brand�o_Costa
```

Are there something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former is double-quoted UTF-8, which prints out normally since your terminal uses UTF-8. The latter is quoted Latin-1, which requires decoding first.

```
>>> print 'Pedro_Miguel_de_Castro_Brand\xe3o_Costa'
Pedro_Miguel_de_Castro_Brand�o_Costa
>>> print 'Pedro_Miguel_de_Castro_Brand\xe3o_Costa'.decode('latin-1')
Pedro_Miguel_de_Castro_Brandão_Costa
```

Comment: I need to add `encode('utf8')` to correctly print out. That is, `print '...'.decode('latin-1').encode('utf8')`. Many thanks for your quick help.